# transform в unity3d (2d)

Tags: unity3d

недавно начал юзать юньку. 
в чем разница между transform.position и transform.Translate? 
в обоих случаях персонаж передвигается. что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно документации по [Transform.Translate()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html), метод принимает опциональный параметр `Space relativeTo = Space.Self`, который определяет вектор, относительно которого будет перемещаться объект.

Различия можно увидеть, если создать на сцене три объекта, к каждому из которых привязать соответствующий скрипт:

1. `PositionMovement` - перемещает объект, изменяя `transform.position`:

   ```
   void Update ()
   {
       transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * 10f * Time.deltaTime);
       transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
   }
   ```
2. `TranslateSelfMovement` - перемещает объект, вызывая метод `transform.Translate` с параметром `Space.Self` (используется по-умолчанию, если опущен)

   ```
   void Update ()
   {
       transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * 10f * Time.deltaTime);
       transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
   }
   ```
3. `TranslateWorldMovement` - перемещает объект, вызывая метод `transform.Translate` с параметром `Space.World`:

   ```
   void Update ()
   {
       transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * 10f * Time.deltaTime);
       transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
   }
   ```

*<sup>Как Вы можете заметить, каждый объект дополнительно вращается вокруг вертикальной оси.</sup>*

Запустив данный пример, Вы увидите, что один объект описывает круги (со скриптом `TranslateSelfMovement`), а два другие устремились вперед.

[image: unity_1]

Если чуть-чуть подкорректировать каждый скрипт, заменив `Vector3.forward` на `transform.forward`, то все объекты будут описывать круги, но у объекта со скриптом `TranslateSelfMovement` радиус круга будет отличаться:

[image: unity_2]